# How to dump memory image OSX Yosemite?

Tags: macos, security, osx-yosemite, computer-forensics

I'm trying to dump a memory image for OSX for Yosemite.  Up to this point, Macmemoryze, but it doesn't support 10.10.  Anyone know of a way to dump the memory to an image file that can be loaded in Volatility?  I did a little searching around and didn't find anything immediately.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSXPMem from Rekall can dump OSX 10.10. See:

http://rekall-forensic.blogspot.de/2015/04/the-pmem-memory-acquisition-suite.html